# Is it possible to exclude article types in a PubMed search?

Tags: literature, research-process, research-tools

I have a question about searching PubMed. I want to search for original research papers while omitting reviews. Is this possible in PubMed?

**Example**

If I am interested in the relation between Acute Renal Failure and Salt, I could use the following search string:

> ("Acute Kidney Injury"[Mesh]) AND ("Sodium Chloride"[Mesh])

Using the column on the left of the article overview list, you can select which article types you are interested in.

**Question**

But I wondered if it was also possible to exclude a specific article type (e.g., reviews) from the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will work:
((Acute Kidney Injury[MeSH Terms]) AND (Sodium Chloride[MeSH Terms])) NOT (Review[Publication Type])

Using the advanced search settings on PubMed it was easy enough to set up, here is the link in case you don't have it already:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/advanced/